# Using FormRequest.from_response() to simulate a user login - FormRequest not defined

Tags: python, scrapy

Not sure if I have a problem with Scrapy or Twisted or ???  Running Python 2.7 32bit and latest scrapy/dependencies via easy_install

Trying to simulate a POST request login and having fits getting it to work.  Went back to the [tutorial from Scrapy](http://readthedocs.org/docs/scrapy/en/latest/topics/request-response.html?highlight=login#using-formrequest-from-response-to-simulate-a-user-login) on doing just this and it doesn't work.

Here is the spider code:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider

class LoginSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'example.com'
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/users/login.php']

    def parse(self, response):
        return [FormRequest.from_response(response,
                    formdata={'username': 'john', 'password': 'secret'},
                    callback=self.after_login)]

    def after_login(self, response):
        # check login succeed before going on
        if "authentication failed" in response.body:
            self.log("Login failed", level=log.ERROR)
            return

        # continue scraping with authenticated session...
_________________________________________
```

Here are the results:

```
C:\Users\jhoiland\scrapy\tutorial>scrapy crawl example.com
2012-01-23 18:59:39-0800 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.14.1 started (bot: tutorial)
2012-01-23 18:59:39-0800 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled extensions: LogStats, TelnetCon
sole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
2012-01-23 18:59:39-0800 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAut
hMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, De
faultHeadersMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, HttpCompressionMi
ddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2012-01-23 18:59:39-0800 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMi
ddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddle
ware
2012-01-23 18:59:39-0800 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled item pipelines:
2012-01-23 18:59:39-0800 [example.com] INFO: Spider opened
2012-01-23 18:59:39-0800 [example.com] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), s
craped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2012-01-23 18:59:39-0800 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 0.0.0.0:602
3
2012-01-23 18:59:39-0800 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 0.0.0.0:6080
2012-01-23 18:59:39-0800 [example.com] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://w
ww.iana.org/domains/example/> from <GET http://www.example.com/users/login.php>
2012-01-23 18:59:39-0800 [example.com] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.iana
.org/domains/example/> (referer: None)
2012-01-23 18:59:39-0800 [example.com] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http:
//www.iana.org/domains/example/>
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 11
78, in mainLoop
            self.runUntilCurrent()
          File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 80
0, in runUntilCurrent
            call.func(*call.args, **call.kw)
          File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 3
62, in callback
            self._startRunCallbacks(result)
          File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 4
58, in _startRunCallbacks
            self._runCallbacks()
        --- <exception caught here> ---
          File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 5
45, in _runCallbacks
            current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
          File "C:\Users\jhoiland\scrapy\tutorial\tutorial\spiders\dmoz.py", lin
**e 8, in parse
            return [FormRequest.from_response(response,
        **exceptions.NameError: global name 'FormRequest' is not defined****

2012-01-23 18:59:39-0800 [example.com] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2012-01-23 18:59:39-0800 [example.com] INFO: Dumping spider stats:
        {'downloader/request_bytes': 426,
         'downloader/request_count': 2,
         'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
         'downloader/response_bytes': 1546,
         'downloader/response_count': 2,
         'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
         'downloader/response_status_count/302': 1,
         'finish_reason': 'finished',
         'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 24, 2, 59, 39, 576000),
         'scheduler/memory_enqueued': 2,
         'spider_exceptions/NameError': 1,
         'start_time': datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 24, 2, 59, 39, 239000)}
2012-01-23 18:59:39-0800 [example.com] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
2012-01-23 18:59:39-0800 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping global stats:
        {}
```

Any idea where to look for the problem?  Did I miss an import or something?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you missed an import:

```
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
```